# How can I set Out-Of-Office in a shared mailbox

Tags: email, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I would want to set the out-of-office automatic response to all emails that arrive to our `info@domain.com`.

currently in the Outlook, I only have one mailbox (the user mailbox) but it has **2 shared mailboxes** setup.

[image]

---

I have tried to create a **Rule** that says:

- for all email received on account `info@domain.com`
- forward to user `ekp@domain.com`

and make that user to set up the Out-of-office message, but it simply did not work, and I suspect that the rules only apply to the user account and not the shared account...

> How can I set Out-Of-Office in this shared mailbox ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way, would be to log into the mailbox via Outlook Web Access and set the OOO reply there.

Comment: Deam, that would indeed be quicker... I'll live my answer for good measure.

Comment: When you say via OWA, I'll assume that you are referring to a direct access (user, pwd), but it's a shared mailbox, so, there is no password. If I add that shared mailbox to my own account, I will have no settings to handle that, and the Auto Reply will be created on my own account: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XjBb0.png and not in the shared mailbox.

Comment: What you are seeing is normal. Your profile is connected to your mailbox, and you are opening a secondary mailbox within your profile. The shared mailbox is going to have a user account associated with it on the server, assuming its not a distribution group, which means it can be logged into and configured for OOO.

Comment: @DanBig sorry, but, how and where can I set this in OWA? small screencast of my choices -> http://bit.ly/K84j5I I can't figure it out, or what you're saying is, because I have the shared mailbox under my visible mailboxes, once I set my own mail to OOO, all emails sent to those shared mailboxes, will be configured with OOO as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set an Out-Off-Office for a shared mailbox (or any other rules that you would like to save on the server for that matter), you first need to create a local profile for the shared mailbox.

You can do this via the Start menu > Control Panel > Mail. When you are adding the new profile, it will ask you to fill out the name, here you should put the name of the shared mailbox. Bonus points for using the full LDAP-path here.

Once the profile is created, open up outlook under that profile and set your OOO by creating a rule via Tools > Rules and Alerts. Make sure you use 'have server reply using a specific message'.

Comment: where do you get the *Mail* menu? I only get this when searching for email: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oSHig.png - Do I need to download [Windows Live Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-live/essentials-home) for this?

Comment: Should be there. You only need an outlook installation for it to pop up. http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/nexus/outlook2010/images/control-panel.png Try typing `control wgpocpl.cpl` in run. (Can't check it now, no Windows in sight)

Answer (score 0):

It is pain in the back to set it up properly. Majority of ways will apply rules not to shared account but to your primary account.Solution:

You need to go to Control Panel>>Mail>>Show profiles click Add.
Give it a name and create a profile and setup new email account for your shared account. Leave password blank and hit 'Finish'. When popup appear change shared email address to your email address ( so change suppport@monkeys.banana to j.doe@monkeys.banana) and put your password in. O365 will like it. Next thing you know you will start Outlook as standalone shared mailbox. Go to Rules and setup:

- send only to me
- have server replying special message
- click on the 'message' link and customize it

When you finish make sure that this rule will become activated.

Enjoy your day.